# Парсинг html в json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Я спарсил информацию с сайта и у меня есть около 1000 `div` на подобии

```
<div 
    style='background-color:#2E2E2E;' 
    botNum='1' 
    id='5' 
    inspectLink='' 
    valueType='Key' 
    amount='52' 
    original-name='Chroma 2 Case Key' 
    title='<div style=\"margin:-8px -8px; padding:3px 10px; padding-bottom:5px; color:#57a857;font-size:16px;background:rgba(26,26,26, 1);\">Chroma 2 Case Key<\/div>' 
    classId='927007517' 
    value='2.85' 
    class="itemImgDiv" 
    clickable='true'>
        <div class='propsWrapper'>
            <span class='number'>
                <b id='num5'>x52</b>
            </span>
            <span class='exterior'></span>
        </div>
        <img src='https:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOie3rKFRh16PKd2pDvozixtSOwaP2ar7SlzIA6sEo2rHCpdyhjAGxr0A6MHezetG0RZXdTA\/91fx68f' onerror=\"this.src='https:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOie3rKFRh16PKd2pDvozixtSOwaP2ar7SlzIA6sEo2rHCpdyhjAGxr0A6MHezetG0RZXdTA\/92fx68f';\" class='itemImg'></img>
        <img src='\/images\/st.png?1' class=\"stImg\" style=\"visibility:none;\"></img>
        <center style='pointer-events:none;'>
            <b id='value5' class='value' style="color: #57a857">        
            <span>$2.85</u></b>
        </center>
</div>
```

Из `div` должен получиться json вида:

```
[{"botNum": "1","amount": "52", "name": "Chroma 2 Case Key", "value" : "2.85"}]
```

Как я могу передать это в json?

Comment: В связи с правилами, вам следует переписать ваш вопрос, на русском языке!

Comment: Поясните свой вопрос. В чем конкретно проблема "передачи в json"?

Comment: я спарсил страницу таким способом $get_content = file_get_contents('https://csgosell.com/phpLoaders/getInventory/getInventory.php', false, $context);
Вся проблема в том,что та страница выдает html,а не json и я не могу понять как переделать html в json читал только по поводу таблиц и то решении было на js

Comment: оформите ваш невалидный html в виде блока Кода, а не цитаты и приведите его к тому виду, как он выглядит на самом деле. Напишите структуру json который хотите получить.

Comment: Исправил как было сказано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно придумать несколько вариантов решения этой задачи. Наиболее простым будет использование регулярных выражений. Другие варианты могут включать приведение исходного html-кода к виду валидного XML и работа с ним, либо какой-то ручной парсинг.

С использованием регулярных выражений искомый результат может быть получен следующим образом (html-код в файле data.txt):

```
$txt = file_get_contents("data.txt");

$fields = [
     'botNum' => "/botNum='([\d]+)'/",
     'amount' => "/amount='([\d]+)'/",
     'name'   => "/name='(.+)'/",
     'value'  => "/value='(.+)'/",
  ];


$result = [];
foreach($fields as $k => $rExp){
    if(preg_match($rExp, $txt, $matches)){
        $result[$k] = $matches[1];
    }
}

print json_encode([$result]);
```

На выходе получаем:

```
[{"botNum":"1","amount":"52","name":"Chroma 2 Case Key","value":"2.85"}]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Почему-то если брать тот код который лежит в теме то все хорошо,а если брать с файла то небольшие проблемы с именем,но тут главное,что вы дали мне идею как это реализовать. Еще раз большое спасибо